# How to Program Segue when the button is clicked the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

When the user clicks the button "next", it has to hide the descriptionTextOutlet and show the datePicker (It´s Ok). But if the user click again the "next" button, my program has to show another View Controller. How can i program a segue to show my other View Controller?

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender{

    if (cont==0){
        self.descriptionTextOutlet.hidden=YES;
        self.datePicker.hidden=NO;
        cont=1;
    } else {
       //What do i have to write here?
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which segue do you want to perform?

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the segue and then call it. Something like the code below:

```
YourNextViewController *nextVC = [[YourNextViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentModalViewController:nextVC animated:YES];
```

Don't forget to thumb up if that was helpful to you

Comment: Thanks ¡¡¡ I wrote what you said. Sadly, when the user clicks the second time, the screen turns black. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't know why is that but maybe you just created a View Controller instead of just pointing to the one you want. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Navigation controller and want to push viewcontroller then

```
UIStoryboard * sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ViewController * view = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_of_your_storyboard"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

And if you want to only present viewcontroller

```
UIStoryboard * sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ViewController * view = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_of_your_storyboard"];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> What this code do:
>
> 1) load storyboard from your main bundle (storyboard_name)
>
> 2) find view controller from your storyboard with given identifier (id_of_your_storyboard)
>
> 3) present or push that view controller
>
> **storyboard_name** -- Name of your story board
>
> **id_of_your_storyboard** -- storyboard id in identity inspector

Comment: Could you explain a bit more of what your presented code does? This would improve the quality of your answer greatly and help future readers understand your solution better.